# I’m reviewing an algebra 2 problem. It is completing the square X^2 +6x +12=0.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is completing the square of X^2 +6x +12=0.As I’m looking at each step they put add 9 on both sides. I’m puzzled on how did they get 9?

[image]

Comment: Because you want to have some $(ax+b)^2$ on the left-hand side. Clearly $a^2=1$ so (up to changing $(a,b)$ into $(-a,-b)$) you can assume $a=1$. Thus $6x=2bx$ so $b=3$. So the remaining term is $b^2=9$.

Comment: Note also that it's a bit silly to subtract $12$ then add $9$. If you know that you want a $9$, then just subtract $3$ from both sides.

Comment: Further reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: @Mindlack for 6x =2bx do you divide them to get 3?

Comment: Focus on the $x^2+6x$. Half of 6 is 3 then do $x^2+6x = (x+3)^2 - 3^2$. Similarly $x^2-6x = (x-3)^2 - 3^2$.  Not $+3^2$ as squaring the bracket creates a $+9$ whether the bracket contains $+3$ or $-3$.

Comment: "for 6x =2bx do you divide them to get 3?"  Of course.  $x^2 + 6x=-12\implies x^2 + 2\cdot 3x=-12\implies x^2+2\cdot 3x + 3^2 = -12 + 3^2\implies x^2+2\cdot 3x +9=-12+9$).

Comment: It is routine.  That is simply *how* you complete the square.  You will, after putting things to one side or the other of the equation and maybe dividing get $x^2 + Kx = M$.  Then you *always* divide $K$ in half and square and add to both sides.  It will *always* work.  $x^2 + Kx = M\implies x^2 + 2(\frac 12 K) + (\frac 12K)^2 = M + (\frac 12K)^2\implies (x +\frac 12K)^2 = M+(\frac 12k)^2$.  If $K$ is $6$ add $9$.  If $K$ is $4$ add $4$.  If $K$ is $16$ add $64$. If $K$ is $2$ add $1$. if $K$ is $7$ add $\frac {49}4$.

Comment: To be fair in a "step by step" expaination they really *need* to add the step "to the side take $6$ and half it to get $3$.  Then square it to git $9$. Now...." Otherwise it's just ... magic....  I could just as easily say... "Factor $x^2 + 6x + 12$ as $(x - (\sqrt 3i + 3))(x + (\sqrt 3i - 3))$ and ...." and your asking "how did I know how to factor as *that*" would be very valid.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$x^2+6x=-12$$ and you want to make the left side equal to a square on the form $(ax+b)^2$, lets expand and compare $$(ax+b)^2=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2$$ we see that

- $a^2x^2=x^2$, so we may choose $a=1$ ($a=-1$ also works)
- $2bx=6x$, so we must have $b=3$

All of the above mean that we may write $$(x+3)^2=x^2+6x+9$$ but as you see we miss $9$, therefore we add it to complete the square.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of rote memorization but... this *is* how you do completing the square.  You put all the terms to one side or another of the equation to get something like:

> $x^2 + Kx = m$.

And then..... you *ALWAYS* .... divide the $K$ in half, square it and add it to both sides.

So $x^2 + 6x = -12$.  Half of $6$ is $3$ and $3^2$ is $9$ so $x^2 + 6x + 9 = -12 + 9$ so $x^2 + 6x + 9 = (x+3)^2 = -3$ and $x + 3 =\pm \sqrt {-3}$.

Or if you had $x^2 + 14x = -13$... half of $14$ is $7$ and $7^2$ is $49$.  So

$x^2 + 14x + 49 = -13 +49$ so $x^2 + 14x + 49 = (x+7)^2 = 36$ and $x +7 =\pm 6$.

Or if you have $x^2 + 5x = 41$ then half of $5$ is $\frac 52$ and $(\frac 52)^2 =\frac {25}4$ so $x^2 + 5x + \frac {25}4 = 41 + \frac {25}4$ so $x^2 + 5x + \frac {25}4 =(x +\frac 52)^2 = \frac {189}4$ so $x+\frac 52 =\pm \sqrt{\frac {189}4}$.

......

Now as to *WHY* why divide $K$ in half and square it.... keep reading.

=======

We have

1. $x^2 + 6x = -12$

we want.....

98. $(x + ???)^2 = !!!!!$

And

97. $(x^2 + 6x + @@@@@@) = !!!!!$

where $(x + ???)^2 = x^2 + 6x + @@@@@@$

So how do we figure out what that $???$ ad $@@@@@$ are?

Well we have $(x + ???)^2 = (x^2 + 2??? + ???^2) = x^2 + 6x + @@@@@$.

So we *must* have $2??? = 6$.  So that means $??? = 3$ and that means $@@@@@ = 3^2 = 9$.

.......

lt;dr

.......

$x^2 + 6x = -12$

so

$x^2 + 2\color{green}{(\frac 62)}x = -12$

$x^2 + 2\color{green}{(\frac 62)}x + (\color{green}{(\frac 62)})^2 =-12 + (\color{green}{(\frac 62)})^2$

$(x +\color{green}{(\frac 62)})^2 = -12 + (\color{green}{(\frac 62)})^2$

.....

ta;dl;l8r

$x^2 + 6x = -12$

$x^2 + 2\cdot\color{red}3 x = -12$

$x^2 + 2\cdot\color{red}3x + \color{red}3^2 = -12 +\color{red}3^2$

$(x + 3)^2 = -12 + 9 = -3$